# Why use a build tool beyond npm/yarn like grunt/gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build

I come from a world of `make` and Unix command pipelines.  As I survey the landscape of tools that integrate better with the world of `node_modules` that I'll use in my build, it seems like there are a half dozen tools out there that have similar functions, and I am trying to understand what factors I should consider before investing effort in learning a new tool (and hopefully not learning every tool out there :))

I think I understand that webpack and npm serve slightly different purposes, and that it might make sense to call webpack from npm but probably not vice versa.

Assuming that I have my dependency management taken care of (npm or yarn install), what should I consider when deciding whether to dive deep into say grunt or gulp vs just chaining together various `script`s in package.json and letting node or yarn do the lifting?

I understand this question is a bit subjective and vague but I hope the key points came through:

- I want something generic but capable
- I want something without non-JS requirements in case there is no compiler present (e.g. make or Go not present in my build env)
- Assume I am using node modules but without any binary or other language dependencies like node-sass or pygments.  I'll be working on unix of some flavor in case that matters.
- I'm hoping you'll describe your CRITERIA as well as advocating for the tool you feel is most capable.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a good [explanation on the npm blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging) that still holds true today. In short, there are lots of tools and no clear winner. In the mean time, npm can be the only build tool you need, for client and server-side dev.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, you are going to make your life the easiest by using whatever has the most support. Currently this seems to be some combination of npm/yarn scripts, webpack, and gulp in different ratios depending on the specifics of what you are doing. Webpack has many plugins that take on common build tasks and thus greatly expand its role as well.